# Displaying Output from Basic API (PHP)

Tags: php, api, sendinblue

So I am using an API (SendInBlue - a transactional email service) and I am trying to use the API to display a list of the users on my webpage.

Below, SendInBlue has given me sample code to use, however when I put them together I just get a blank screen.

I know this is a total beginner question... but how do I put these 2 pieces of code together so that it actually displays the list of contacts on my website?

Thank you so much!!

**EXAMPLE**

```
require('../mailin.php');
$mailin = new Mailin("https://api.sendinblue.com/v2.0","your access key");
$data = array( "listids" => array(1,2),
  "timestamp" =>"2015-05-22 14:30:00",
  "page" => 1,
  "page_limit" => 2
);

var_dump($mailin->display_list_users($data));
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

```
{ 
  "code":"success",
  "message":"Retrieved details of all users for the given lists",
  "data":{
      "data":[
        {
          "blacklisted":0,
          "email":"email1@domain.com",
          "id":1,
          "listid":[1],
          "blacklisted_sms":1,
          "last_modified" : "2015-05-22 15:30:00"
        },
        {
          "blacklisted":1,
          "email":"email2@domain.com",
          "id":2,
          "listid":[1,2],
          "blacklisted_sms":0 ,
          "last_modified" : "2015-05-25 19:10:30"        
        }
      ],
  "page":1,
  "page_limit":2,
  "total_list_records":100
  }
}
```

Comment: add `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the very top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out. I turned every attribute into a variable like so...

```
$subscriberemail = $getemails['data']['data'][$number]['email'];
```

This took ages to figure out!